# Java Azure SDK to access Azure File Share using AD creds

Tags: java, azure, fileshare

I'm trying to connect to Azure File share using Java SDK with AD Creds, The below link talks about the approach to connect to file share using AD User Delegation Access. But when i go thru the link it circles back to using the connection string. I'm looking for an approach to connect to file share with AD creds instead of Account/Access key/Connection String. Is there an approach available or only option is to use the connection string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Answer (score 0):

As your provided link says, A user delegation SAS can only work for Blob storage. There is no way to connect to file share with AD Credential. Apart from connection string, there are serval ways to connect to file share, such as SAS Token. You can refer to this [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.file.share.shareserviceclientbuilder?view=azure-java-stable).

> A user delegation SAS is secured with Azure Active Directory (Azure
> AD) credentials and also by the permissions specified for the SAS. A
> user delegation SAS applies to Blob storage only.

Comment: yes True but somewhere in the documentation i thought seeing the user delegation sas work for all Azure Storage. If not AD then we might have to go thru regular way of using connection String or Sas token via account access keys.